The proof of the graph is nonseparable either $G\backslash e$ or $G/ e$ is nonseparable
Today, while reading Bondy's book "Graph Theory", I encountered a problem. It says that an edge $e$ of a nonseparable graph $G$ is called deletable if $G\setminus e$ is nonseparable, and contractible if $G / e$ the graph obtained by contracting edge $e$ in $G$ is nonseparable. Show that every edge of a nonseparable graph is either deletable or contractible. I've come up with a proof on my own, but I'm unsure whether it's correct. I hope someone can offer some guidance.  Here is my proof:
Let $G$ be a nonseparable graph, and let $e$ be an edge of $G$. We aim to show that $e$ is either deletable or contractible.
Step 1: Nonseparability of $G$
Since $G$ is nonseparable, it is connected, and no vertex removal disconnects the graph. This property will carry over (to some extent) when we delete or contract $e$, as long as $G \setminus e$ or $G / e$ remains connected.
Step 2: Deleting or contracting $e$
Consider the following cases for $e$:

Case 1: $G \setminus e$ is nonseparable
If removing $e$ does not create articulation points and leaves $G \setminus e$connected, then $e$ is deletable, and the statement is satisfied.

Case 2: $G \setminus e$ is separable
In this case, removing $e$ creates articulation points or disconnects $G \setminus e$, so $e$ is not deletable. We now consider $G / e$, the graph obtained by contracting $e$:

Contracting $e$ merges its two endpoints into one vertex. Since $G$ is nonseparable, contracting $e$ cannot create articulation points (as this would imply that $e$ was already critical for separability in $G$).
Furthermore, contracting $e$ does not disconnect the graph. Thus, $G / e$ remains nonseparable, and $e$ is contractible.



In all cases, $e$ is either deletable or contractible. Therefore, for every edge $e$ in $G$, one of these two properties holds.
